# Projection of 2 parallel vectors onto column space of matrix M is the same

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can anyone please explain why the projection of 2 parallel vectors is the same?

EDIT (lacking details):
The projection vector of the vector returns the projection onto the column space of a matrix M.

The length/norm of these 2 parallell vectors is different, since they are parallell you can say one vector is the same as the other, but multiplied with a constant.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Projection onto where? Do they have same magnitude?

Comment: parallel vectors can have different modulus, and in this case the projections on third vector are different.

Comment: Length of the vectors are different, which is what makes me confused.

Answer (score 1):

We define
$$
\operatorname{proj}_u(x) = \frac{x \cdot u}{u \cdot u}u
$$
Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are (non-zero) parallel vectors.  Then there is some unit vector $\hat u$ such that $u = a\hat u$ and $v = b \hat u$ for some non-zero constants $a,b$.  We have
$$
\operatorname{proj}_u(x) = \frac{x \cdot u}{u \cdot u}u = 
\frac{x \cdot a \hat u}{a \hat u \cdot a \hat u}a\hat u = 
\frac{a^2}{a^2} \frac{x \cdot \hat u}{\hat u \cdot \hat u}\hat u =
\operatorname{proj}_{\hat u}(x)
$$
similarly, $\operatorname{proj}_v(x) = \operatorname{proj}_{\hat u}(x)$.  So, the two projections are equal.

Comment: This is a correct reason why we should get the same result when we project a given vector onto two different parallel vectors. But it's not clear what is being projected onto what in the original question. Awaiting clarification from OP.

Comment: @DavidK I interpret the "projection of a vector" to mean the projection onto that vector.

Comment: As *DavidK* said, that's not the usual definition of "projection of". Usually when we project some object x onto another object y, we get a projection z, which we refer to as "the projection of x onto y".